# Protección de vídeos con Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, jwt, stream, tokens

He seguido los ejemplos para subir, codificar y encriptar vídeos en Azure Media Services y todo funciona correctamente, pero tengo un problema con la protección de los vídeos.

La aplicación web que mostrará el reproductor, basado en Azure Media Player, obtiene un token válido para el asset correspondiente que luego se entrega al reproductor para que se inicie el streaming.

Pero tanto la url como el token quedan expuestos si alguien quisiese volver a utilizarlos de forma ajena a mi aplicación web.

¿Hay alguna forma de solicitar un token de un solo uso?
¿Existe alguna forma de modificar la validación de tokens del lado de Azure Media Services?

He probado a restringir la validez del token con el parámetro `expires` de `JwtSecurityToken`, pero no parece ser muy preciso. Buscando encontré referencias al parámetro `clockskew`, pero tampoco he encontrado cómo podría modificar su valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que sí se puede especificar el número de veces que un token puede ser utilizado para solicitar una licencia a Azure Media Services, con el parámetro `maxuses`

Tan solo hay que añadir un claim de este tipo:

```
New Claim("urn:microsoft:azure:mediaservices:maxuses", 1)
```

De esta forma se limita a un solo uso.

Más información en este enlace:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/content-protection-overview#controlling-content-access